# How to turn a time axis into a frequency axis?

Tags: experimental-physics, fourier-transform, data-analysis

I'm currently trying to obtain the temperature of a rubidium cell that I used in an experiment. I performed a Gaussian fit on my data but now I'm supposed to take the differences between the peaks to convert my x axis from time to frequency, particularly in MHz. Here is my data.

[image]

I'm supposed to use the energy transitions of Rubidium pictured here to help, so that I can determine the temperature of the rubidium cells through the widths of the peaks, but I'm not sure how to read these in a way that would help me convert my temporal axis into a frequency one to even get started on that...

[image]

This is the last part of the manual, so I'm anxious to be able to figure this out and complete my writeup. What should I do to translate my axis?

Comment: A number of comments deleted. To answer the question, post an answer.

Comment: Ordinarily one would Fourier transform, but if you have tens of milliseconds of data that fits in an Excel spreadsheet, you’re not directly sensitive to megahertz oscillations. You say “my data” and “temperature” but you don’t say anything about what you’re actually measuring. My guess is that you are sweeping some control parameter over time, so time is a linear proxy for the quantity you are actually changing. Is it a radio frequency? Is it an optical wavelength of some tunable laser?

Comment: @rob My apologies. I am measuring a tunable laser with wavelength 780.24 nm fired through a rubidium cell, with an adjustable current to tune the laser to resonance with atomic transitions where we would see a fluorescent light, with each peak representing a point of resonance. I'm supposed to determine the difference in position of the peaks in MHz and then use that to determine the temperature of the cell.

Comment: $f=1/T$ but it's giving frequencies that are too small, should your time be in microseconds?